# Get all possible string's partitions in which each partition is a palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, palindrome

I am having a hard time debugging the error i am making here

Given a string s, partition s such that every string of the partition is a palindrome. Return all possible palindrome partitioning of s. For example, given s = "aab", Return [ ["a","a","b"] ["aa","b"], ]

```
def ispalindrome(self,s,i,j):
    while (i < j):
        if (s[i] != s[j]):
            return False
        i+=1
        j-=1
    return True
def helper(self,i,current,s,ans):
    if(i==len(s)):
        ans.append(current)
        return
    for j in range(i,len(s)):
        if(self.ispalindrome(s,i,j)):
            current.append(s[i:j+1])
            self.helper(j + 1, current, s, ans)
            current.pop()
def partition(self, A):
    current=[]
    ans=[]
    self.helper(0, current, A, ans)
    return ans
```

by calling the partition function this returns an empty list don't know why,
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results you want by changing:

`ans.append(current)`

To:

`ans.append(current[:])`

Or:

`ans.append([] + current)`

I think the problem was that you were appending the list `current` to `ans` and elsewhere in your code, you were popping off values in `current` (which affected the list you had stored in `ans`).

By appending a list slice, `current[:]`, it is sort of a copy of the `current` list and not the list itself  :-)

The second solution does in effect what the first does. It appends a fresh list address, `[]`, to `ans` and concatenates the values from `current` to the fresh address.

I got the results `[['a', 'a', 'b'], ['aa', 'b']]` running your code with the change.

Comment: Thanks Chris really helpful for me :)